# how can use string for access value of object?

Tags: javascript

at first please see image then, how can use for example:
use this `humans.body."name"` instead of this `humans.body.name`? is there any way to solve that?

[image]

my codes:

```
//this is my file
let fileJson = {
status: 200,
result: {
author_id: "137",
text: "1281ms",
author: "Ctrl+Z",
},
};

let data = [{id: 1, key: "author_id"}];

console.log(fileJson.result.author_id); //output: 137
console.log(data[0].key); //output: author_id
console.log(fileJson.result.data[0].key); //output: Uncaught TypeError ...

//how can solve this error?
```

thank you :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this notation to access the property:

```
fileJson.result[data[0].key]
```

Comment: excellent! glad to help. you may want to mark the answer as "accepted" if it has solved your problem.

Comment: _"you may want to mark the answer as "accepted""_ - You might want to close this as dupe instead of adding an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Values can be accessed a couple of ways.  Use the array accessor with the key value.

```js
//this is my file
let fileJson = {
  status: 200,
  result: {
    author_id: "137",
    text: "1281ms",
    author: "Ctrl+Z",
  },
};

let data = [{
  id: 1,
  key: "author_id"
}];

console.log(fileJson.result.author_id); //output: 137
console.log(data[0].key); //output: author_id
console.log(fileJson.result[data[0].key]);
```

Comment: Yes, I had forgotten this. thanks 

Comment: How about searching for a dupe for such a easy and popular question?